# Doubts about Intents and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, manifest

Im quite new on Android programming, so I have some basic doubts.

There is an App here that do not have the BroadcastReceiver, but I used other class instead, and I am sure that it works properly.

I read in some topics, that i need to register It in manifest, but I have no clue how to do It; and I got confused about `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND` and etc, I do not know how to set it.

**Question:** Can I ask for someone explain to me, in **simple way**, what I need to do to my method be executed while the app is closed, AND, how i register it on manifest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an `Intent` is the way of Android of telling to everyone that some event occured.

For instance where your device receive a call an `Intent` is broadcast. But to be specific to some event every `Intent` has an *action*. For instance the `Intent` broascast when you receive a SMS has the `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"` action.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` you can register objects for specific intents. You can register `Activity`, `Service` and `BroadcastReceiver`.

To register a `BroadcastReceiver` to "receive sms action"  you do the following in your manifest :

```
<receiver android:name="your.receiver.class">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This means that every time an `Intent` with the specified action is fired, it will be pass to your receiver. This means that his `onReceive` method will be called with the intent as param.

So to create some code that will be executed will your app is closed, follow this steps :

1. Create a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`.
2. Put your code in the `onReceive` method. This method will be call every time your receiver receive an intent.
3. Register your receiver for the desired action in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: But this should work with the app closed? Because i was reading my manifest, now that you made it very clear for me, thanks btw, it has `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`, so it means that should start when the app start, right? Or im wrong? And is there any action that works whe the app is closed?

Comment: As you can read in the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED, an intent with this action is broadcast once when the system has booted. If you register you receiver for intent with this action (and declare the associated permission), it will be start once when the device done booting.

Answer (score 0):

**BroadcastTeceiver** as the name imply is component that could receive data that someone send via Intents. The sender could be the system, other App or your App itself.

There are to ways to regiester BroadcastReceiver:

1. In the manifest by exlixit the Intent you want to listen.
2. In code by give it Intent_filter programmatically.